# Как на чистом C передать имя типа в функцию?

Tags: c, шаблоны, типы

Нужно передать в функцию имя типа на этапе выполнения (не компиляции!!! Макроопределение не подходят!). Как это сделать?

Comment: Строкой :) Изложите, что именно вы хотите. Что вы понимаете под "передать имя типа"?

Comment: Чтобы функция знала тип элемента

Comment: Ну используйте функцию с переменным числом аргументов (которая с тремя точками).

Comment: но мне ведь по сути динамическая типизация нужна, разве это поможет?

Comment: Ну,  а как вы себе это представляете иначе? Допустим, такая возможность есть - как в идеале должен віглядеть ваш код?

Comment: `enum { .. }` не помогает ?

Comment: Расскажите подробнее, что вы пытаетесь сделать.

Comment: Наверное проще всего  передать указатель и тип (кстати, если типов мало, то тип можно упаковать в указатель (на практике туда можно впихнуть десяток бит, но это сильно системозависимо)), но можно сделать   это  так же, как в printf/scanf (через varargs (`#include <stdarg.h>`))

Answer (score 6):

В `C` нет ни шаблонов, ни `RTTI` как в `C++`, или подобных механизмов, отсутствует рефлексия или интроспекция. Но есть несколько способов:

- *variadic arguments* (`va_arg(args,<type>)`)

  ```c
  void f(const char* fmt, ...) {
      va_list args;
      va_start(args,fmt);
      for (const char* ptr = fmt; *ptr != '\0'; ++ptr) {
          if (*ptr == 'd') {
              double arg = va_arg(args,double);
          }
      }
      va_end(args);
  }
  ```
- *type erasure* (`T* -> void* -> T*`)

  ```c
  typedef enum { /* ... */ } Type;

  typedef struct {
      Type type;
      void* ptr;
  } Test;

  void f(Test* test) {
      if (test->type == TYPE) {
          T* ptr = test->ptr;
          ptr->implementation;
      }
  }

  int main() {
      T t;
      Test test;
      test.type = TYPE;
      test.ptr = (void*)&t;
      f(&test);
      return 0;
  }
  ```
- `union`:

  ```c
  #include <stdio.h>

  typedef enum {
      FLOAT, DOUBLE, LDOUBLE,
      INT, SHORT, LONG, UINT, USHORT, ULONG
  } Type;

  typedef struct {
      Type type;
      union {
          float f;
          double d;
          long double ld;
          int si;
          short ss;
          long sl;
          unsigned ui;
          unsigned short us;
          unsigned long ul;
      };
  } Test;

  void f(Test* test) {
      switch (test->type) {
          case FLOAT:   printf("float %f",test->f); break;
          case DOUBLE:  printf("double %lf",test->d); break;
          case LDOUBLE: printf("long double %Lf",test->ld); break;
          case INT:     printf("int %d",test->si); break;
          case SHORT:   printf("short %hd",test->ss); break;
          case LONG:    printf("long %ld",test->sl); break;
          case UINT:    printf("unsigned int %u",test->ui); break;
          case USHORT:  printf("unsigned short %hu",test->us); break;
          case ULONG:   printf("unsigned long %lu",test->ul); break;
      }
  }

  int main() {
      Test test;

      test.type = DOUBLE;
      test.d = 3.14159;
      f(&test);

      test.type = USHORT;
      test.us = (unsigned short)31459;
      f(&test);

      return 0;
  }
  ```

Answer (score 1):

В Си невозможно корректно принять внешние данные просто так, ваша программа должна знать протокол связи, структуры пакетов, и алгоритм обработки. Всё точно так-же как на передающей стороне. Иначе получится каша.
Всё данные что создаются внутри программы - уже имеют известный тип, и могут быть обработаны на уровне предварительной компиляции. Можно упростить обработку, позволив компилятору самостоятельно выбирать функции обработки данных. Для этого есть макрос "_Generic((X)".
Пример - https://github.com/AVI-crak/Rtos_cortex/blob/master/sPrint.h

```
#define dpr_(X) _Generic((X),           \
const char*:        soft_print_con, \
char*:              soft_print,     \
char:               print__char,    \
uint8_t:            print_uint8,    \
uint16_t:           print_uint16,   \
uint32_t:           print_uint32,   \
uint64_t:           print_uint64,   \
int8_t:             print_int8,     \
int16_t:            print_int16,    \
int32_t:            print_int32,    \
int64_t:            print_int64,    \
float:              print_float,    \
double:             print_double,   \
default:            print_hex       \
```

)(X)

Кроме того вам наверняка понадобится древний злой макрос передачи неизвестного типа данных в саму функцию "**attribute**((transparent_union))". Это древнее зло позволяет отправить в функцию всё что угодно без приведения типа. И если сама функция будет знать что это такое (+1 дополнительный параметр) - то внутри можно работать с данными через объединение, без ошибок и предупреждений.

Comment: Протокол, пакеты... Тут речь ведь не про сетевую передачу. Необязательно все данные имеют известный тип. `void*` - как раз пример того, когда типа может не быть. Библиотека вполне может вернуть `void*` или какой нибудь `struct`, в котором будет поле с типом `unsigned char*`. В последнем случае, хотя тип и известен, по сути это просто байтовый массив, в котором может быть всё что угодно.

Comment: Вы должны создать переменную, структуру, или указатель на свободную память перед выполнением функции из библиотеки - для того чтобы она могла корректно сохранить свои данные. Это известно до выполнения функции. Иначе код просто не соберётся.

Comment: Неа, вот `FFmpeg`, например, вернёт вам `AVFrame` с полем `opaque` с типом `void*`. Вы просто открыли медиконтейнер для вывода, вы запросто можете ничего не знать о том, что там лежит.

Comment: Я верно понял - библиотечная функция отдаёт блок данных известного размера с неизвестным содержимым? Если это так, то единственный способ разобраться - парсить данные до просветления. Для этого нет макросов, или крутых штук из Си++. Всё придётся писать самостоятельно.

Comment: Так и есть, это нормально, в этом вся сила Си. В чистом Си даже можно накостылить ООП с наследованием.